# Making application globally available in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, ffmpeg

I've downloaded ffmpeg and placed it in a folder, say `/user/bla`. Now every time I wish to run ffmpeg, i need to enter

`system:random/path user$ /user/bla/ffmpeg [arguments]`

Can I make the application globally available so that I can run it from each path, just by doing

`system:random/path user$  ffmpeg [arguments]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, either add /user/bla to your PATH variable, or make a symlink from /user/bla/ffmpeg into a directory that is already in your PATH variable, like /usr/local/bin/

This will make all executables in /user/bla available to your current account:

```
echo 'PATH=$PATH:/user/bla' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

This will make just ffmpeg available to all accounts:

```
sudo ln -s /user/bla/ffmpeg /usr/local/bin/
```